# SortBy() function crashing excel 365

Tags: excel, sorting, crash

My *.xlsb workbook seems to be crashing when calculating when this sortby() formula is changed from row 23 to 24

```
=SORTBY(J3:L23,J3:J23,1,L3:L23,-1)
```

The data in the reference cells are also formulas. There didn't seem to be any issue with this until I changed the sortby formula to account for an additional row in the source array. Any ideas?

Comment: I have not faced this yet, but i have faced the same problem while using `GROUPBY()` or `PIVOTBY()` or `BYCOL()` or `BYROW()` or `SCAN()` without `LAMBDA()` construct with `.xlsb` but not with `.xlsx` , i have raised this problem but they **(MS)** have not replied yet, may be thats because of the `Beta` testing but it seems your scenario is different

Comment: I thought this might be an issue but I tried converting to xlsx to test and having same issue.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to paste some sample data as text. Also what formulas are there on those referenced cells.

Answer (score 0):

The original file must have been corrupted or something to cause this crash. I was able to solve the problem by copying and pasting to a new workbook.